# Is there a way to use formula in filtering a dataset in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: style, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I am very new to Mapbox and was wondering if anyone knew how to filter a layer based on a formula defined for a field in that layer. For example, I have a 'depth' field in the data and I want to display all the lines that have depth <=500 and is completely divisible by 100 (with no remainder). So the result should look something like this: show only the lines that have depth 100, 200, 300, 400, and 500. There is something like this for styling the layer as a text symbol but for symbolizing the layer as a line, the only option I get is a filter where I need to choose a specific value and not use a formula.

Comment: There is an explanation of such filtering operation in styles manual. Here you are: https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#filter

Comment: Thank you. That is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in two parts

First, apply the filter property as:

```
"filter": 
[
  "<=",
  "depth",
  500
]
```

Second,then in paint property of line

`"paint": {
    "line-color": ["case",
    ["==", 
      [
        "%",
        [
          "to-number",
          [
            "get",
            "depth"
          ]
        ],
        100
      ], 0],
      "red",//color you want to give for lines divisible by 100
      "blue"//color similar to background or any color
],
"line-opacity":["case",
    ["==", 
      [
        "%",
        [
          "to-number",
          [
            "get",
            "depth"
          ]
        ],
        100
      ], 0],
      "1",//opacity given for lines divisible by 100
      "0"//opacity zero will not show other lines
 ]
}`

Example Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p5d2gvn3/1/

Comment: Thank you. It worked!